# In Word 2010 VBA use find and replace to insert space characters before and after a symbol

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a Word 2010 document with some plus minus symbols surrounded by numbers.
I would like to format the plus minus symbols so that there is an empty space before and after each plus minus symbol.

My code is able to find the symbol.
Unfortunately, the ReplaceString leaves a white box instead of the plus minus symbol.

```
Dim ReplaceString As String
ReplaceString = " " & ChrW(-3919) & " "

Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Replacement.Highlight = True
With Selection.Find
    .Text = ChrW(-3919) 'plus/minus symbol
    .Forward = True
    .Format = True
    .MatchCase = False
    .Replacement.Text = ReplaceString
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
With ActiveDocument.Range.Find
  .ClearFormatting
  .Text = ChrW(-3919) 'plus/minus symbol
  With .Replacement
    .ClearFormatting
    .Highlight = True
    .Text = " ^& "
  End With
  .Format = True
  .Forward = True
  .Wrap = wdFindContinue
  .MatchCase = False
  .MatchWholeWord = False
  .MatchWildcards = False
  .MatchSoundsLike = False
  .MatchAllWordForms = False
  .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End With
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. So this means the characters   ^&  in the replacement string represent the find string.

Comment: Yes, that's a standard Replace expression, which you can find via 'Special' pop-up in the Find/Replace dialogue